# Getting value by key from Exception.Data c#

Tags: c#, exception

I want to use the `Data` property to store information I want to throw in a new exception and I've figured out how I can loop through each of the `DictionaryEntries` with   this snippet

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in ex.Data)
```

But what I'd prefer to do is get the value by its key name because I have different object types in that `Data` object. Its easier to cast them to the right kind of object if I can get the value by its key name.

Anyone know how to get the `Exception.Data` dictionary entries by key name?

Comment: What do you mean?  `DictionaryEntry` gives you both a `Key` and `Value` property that you can read from. What else do you need?

Comment: use `de.key` inside the loop

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know the key it would be much more efficient to use the Dictionary for what it is good for:

```
var yourObj = ex.Data["your_key"];
```

Comment: And because `ex.Data["your_key"]` will simply return `null` if the key doesn't exist in the `IDictionary`, you can even implement some kind of `KeyNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 9):

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in ex.Data)
{
    if (de.Key == "something")
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```